# select specific data from dataset in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net, dataset

i'm working on my school project. I've generated a dataset of SQL Server Compact edition database using `visual studio's 'Data Set Configuration Wizard'`.

I've a table named 'User'. I want to fill 'User' table of 'dataset' with only those records which meet specific criteria. but when i call 'adapter.Fill(ds.User)' it fills table with all the data from database's table.

i tried to set 'SELECT' command of adapter as

```
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName = {0}", userName);
```

but this is also not working. can anyone tell me how to specify 'WHERE' clause in 'SELECT' command of 'adapter'?

here is the image
http://s3.postimg.org/4pqb9cwyr/error.png

here is the code also

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Student_s_Expense_Manager
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create 'User' Table Adapter
            ExpenseDataSetTableAdapters.UserTableAdapter userAdapter = new ExpenseDataSetTableAdapters.UserTableAdapter();

            // Create a Dataset of ExpenseDataSet
            ExpenseDataSet expenseDataset = new ExpenseDataSet();

            string userName = textBoxUserName.Text;

            userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE UserName = '{0}'", userName);
            userAdapter.Fill(expenseDataset.User);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Image is not found. Please paste the code.

Comment: On which line you are getting the error

Comment: Your problem isn't related to your query. See my edited answer below.

Comment: i'm getting error on 
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE UserName = '{0}'", userName);
and error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
i think 'adapter' doesn't initialize 'SelectCommand' before 'Fill()' mehtod. When we call 'Fill()' method it then also initialize all the 'Commands' of dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typed data adapter does indeed only init its `SelectCommand` when the `Fill` method is called. So unfortunately it will be hard for you to set the query you want with that in your way. I would advise that you quit using wizards and master the [ado.net](/questions/tagged/ado.net) mechanics but that's beyond the scope of your question. Still, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be of interest.

That aside, your actual formatting of the query is wrong. If `UserName` is `varchar` your comparison will expect apostrophes ( `'` ) surrounding your user name value. You must also make sure that your value will double any apostrophes it may itself contain so that Sql Server will interpret them as a char rather than a delimiter.

```
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText =
    string.Format("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName = '{0}'", userName.Replace("'", "''"));
```

Or better yet, use a parameter to protect your code from [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText =
    "SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName = @UserName";
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
```

Comment: if i use "adapter.Fill()" first and then set CommandText then there will be no use because "Fill()" method will first fill dataset with all data from table.

Comment: when i tries to set 'CommandText' i get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I can't step over
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText =
    "SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName = @UserName";

Comment: @ZohaibAslam Refresh the page and read my first paragraph again. :)

Comment: i think i've to set 'SelectCommand' in 'Designer' generated code. then it should work

Comment: @ZohaibAslam what you *really* should do IMHO is stop using wizard-generated adapters. They just get in your way. Do use typed datasets but drop the adapters and make your own.

Comment: i've a good grip on ADO.NET 2.0 :)
i was just trying to learn something new. I think now i should write my own adapters and stop using these 'Wizards'

Comment: @ZohaibAslam it appears you are correct about typed adapters: they do init the `SelectCommand` only when `Fill` method is called. I edited my answer.

Comment: yep :) when i debug my code then i observed that Commands are initialized when 'Fill' is called. now i've re-write my select command in designer generated code and it's working perfectly :P

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName = '{0}'", userName);
```

You actually forgot to add colons `' '` around username

Comment: if i set "CommandText" before filling the dataset i get the following error
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: i got the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: You should show us the full code and the line where you are getting the error

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose strings in quotes in a SQL statement:

```
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = 
    string.Format("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName = '{0}'", userName);
```

**However, you should NOT do this in a real application.**  For a school project you're OK but you should get in the habit of using parameters instead:

```
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText =
    string.Format("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserName = @UserName");
userAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",userName);
```

Do some research on SQL injection to understand why.